# Can this site be built using wordpress or Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I want to know if this site can be built with wordpress, I'm a programmer and I don't know anything about wordpress, how I'm just to get some good advices from you guys:

The main aim of the site is to allow users to view several places of interest in a country

Administrator:

1. create a place of interest
2. add,delete,edit details such as place name, address, location with
   google map,rating(users can vote a place),latitude, longitude
3. add reviews for place on interest

Users:

1. allow users to register

   2.contribute to site by adding a place of interest with all its
   details(will then be approved by the administator)

   3.add reviews to a place of interest

   4.up vote or downvote a place of interest

One more thing, do you think it would be better to use Drupal to build it rather than Wordpress??

Comment: The learning curve with Drupal is a lot steeper than Wordpress but it is a much more powerful CMS tool. If you're willing to put the time in then I'd recommend Drupal. Personally I don't think Wordpress seems very professional.

Comment: I'm wanting to go with wordpress because of its large community and also the widgets and plugins availability

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to do something along these lines with Wordpress. I'm a designer (I only really understand the basics of PHP programming) and I've used an Events Manager Plugin to do all of those things. ([You can view the plugin here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/).)

It allowed me to create venues & events, had google maps to show the venue location and also had a reviews / ratings area for each. There were also areas that allowed me to enable registered users submitting events and venues.

So, yes, it's definitely possible for these things to be done in Wordpress. :)

Comment: Also, if you're looking to pickup programming with Wordpress, Lynda.com and tutsplus.com both have good courses you can take.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is "sure!"
I am a developer as well and I was just at the [Wordcamp 2012 Victoria](http://2012.victoria.wordcamp.org/tag/wordcamp-victoria-2012/) yesterday where [Morten Rand-Hendriksen gave a one hour talk](http://www.designisphilosophy.com/events/speaking-engagements-events/can-wordpress-really-do-that-slides-from-my-wordcamp-victoria-2012-presentation/) titled:

> CAN WORDPRESS REALLY DO THAT?

As Marten mentioned in his talk, if you think of wordpress as a machine that spits out html and javascript, then you realize that pretty much anything can be done with wordpress. Wordpress is very simple and organized platform that would make it easier for you to focus on adding whatever crazy functionality you need to add to your website while still giving you full control. However, almost everything on your list are problems that have been solved and you can easily find sample codes or tutorials by searching around. In fact the case study that Marten presented was very similar to your requirements in many ways.

In terms of getting started with Wordpress development, make sure to do your homework and familiarize yourself a bit with the platform and best practices, to avoid any potential problems down the road. [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) will be your best friend while developing your Wordpress website. Good luck with your project!